# sftp channel outbound adapter with retry

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

I am using spring batch and spring integration where once my batch job is completed,it creates texts files and those needs to be uploaded to some ftp server. Sometimes we noticed that those connections drops and it needs to be retried. Is there anyway we can use spring retry project to try few sec later to see if it can upload those files. we want it to be configurable.

If so is there any example out there.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Spring Integration provide `retry` component for you. It is called `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice`:

```
<int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter>
    <int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice" />
    </int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Please, find more info in the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain).

Consider to you use `RequestHandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice` also for your "connections drops" cases.

And here you are the [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/retry-and-more).

Comment: Cool!!!! This is what i was looking for. All the diff way of managing retry. Awesome.